# Rotate SMS providers to get around 200 messages per day limit?

Tags: sms

According to this twilio page (https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/messaging-in-production/1.html#long-or-short-code) - if you send more than 200 SMS messages per day while using a "long code" you can have your account suspended or filtered.

Has anyone worked on an extension to rotate between multiple accounts to avoid hitting this 200 contact limit?

Answer (score 2):

That is a total hack, and is therefore the wrong solution to the problem.

If they have these limits it's for a reason. Ultimately Twilio may be the wrong provider for you, or you're on the wrong plan with them.

Suggestion: research other providers.

Comment: As the question is asked... you're 100% correct. The paragraph after the one linked actually has all the information about why :). I'd like to add that Jamie may be asking about/need to look into "Pooling multiple long codes" (further down the page or https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/messaging-in-production/1.html#pooling-long-codes). There's even a code sample!

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a ticket upstream and submitted a patch:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21138